# 14 x 14 LED Matrix - How can I control it?

Tags: arduino, led, multiplexer, led-matrix

I intend to build a 14 x 14 standard 3mm blue LED matrix, for a WordClock-like project, but I have no idea how to control it.
I've heard of multiplexing with NPN transistors, but I'm concerned about the resistors values. And still, 28 ports it's still too much for my Arduino Nano.

What can I do to control the LEDs? Is the multiplexing idea right, or am I completely on the wrong path?

Answer (score 1):

Use a LED driver such as the [TLC5940](http://www.ti.com/product/tlc5940) to control the columns as well as current and PMOSFETs such as the [IRLML6402](http://www.irf.com/part/_/A~IRLML6402) connected to a pair of 74HC138s to control the rows.

Program the '5940, activate the row, activate the '5940, wait the appropriate duration, deactivate the row, and move on to the next row. Repeat until you have a vibrant 14x14 LED matrix.